# GIthub Pages with React without using CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, redux

I've created a React/Redux app that I didn't use CRA to create. All the tutorials I've seen on Github Pages assumes you have used CRA to create it.

One of the tutorials I saw had a 'build' script, I don't have one of those and I don't even know if I need it to get on to Github Pages.

I've followed the generic Github Pages and have it on my Github project with a branch called 'gh-branch' however I'm getting a 404 error. Any help with this would be appreciated

package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux-api-opendota",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "working with redux and api",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": "http://kevin6767.github.io/redux-api-opendota2",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
},
```

Comment: You will need a build script because your predeploy calls `npm run build` and you need to build the app before you can host it on gh pages

Comment: I should have mentioned this, I tried to one of the tutorials and there suggestions was to use ```build: react-scripts build ``` however, when i tried to npm install react-scripts it threw me an error because I had webpack. I know it sounds like a mess, but my app works flawlessly besides trying to get it on github pages

Comment: CRA - Canada Revenue Agency?

Answer (score 0):

Your branch [`gh-pages`](https://github.com/kevin6767/redux-api-opendota2/tree/gh-pages) must have `index.html` (and the entire content of `public/`) at the root. See the docs at

https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites

The branch shouldn't be a fork of `master`, it should be an [orphan](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt) branch that only contains files to be published, not sources to generate the files. So my advice is to recreate the branch:

```
git branch -D gh-pages
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
# copy index.html from master
git show master:public/index.html >index.html
git add .
git commit -m "GitHub pages — initial commit"
git push origin +gh-pages
```

Another approach is to have directory `docs/` in branch master. SO you can rename your `public/` to `docs/` and don't use `gh-pages` at all.

Comment: everything seemed to be working correctly until I got to ```git push origin gh-pages``` It is saying updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind and it's suggesting to git pull, but I don't want to merge anything do I?

Comment: Yep, you're overriding an existing branch. It requires force-pushing. Either `git push origin +gh-pages` or `git push -f origin gh-pages`

Comment: and after I do this I should be able to open the github pages? or do I need more setup

Comment: Already here: https://kevin6767.github.io/redux-api-opendota2/

Comment: error with the bundle? I've never seen that before. I've never used bundle, I've copied and pasted that html page a ton.

Comment: https://kevin6767.github.io/dist/bundle.js — error 404. The bundle is not in the branch.

Comment: I've never seen that before I've always used this https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658 to help me remember how to build react apps from scratch.